# Problema con consulta en sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Me encuentro realizando consultas a una base de datos en sql sin embargo me ha mandado el siguiente error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tengo 3 tablas en mi base de datos, tabla producto, tabla comprador y tabla ventas, con las cuales he estado trabajando. Mi problema empieza cuando tengo que sumar la cantidad total de productos comprados por una persona, cabe mencionar que dicha persona puede realizar varias compras, entonces debo mostrar la cantidad total de productos por cada una.

Mi codigo para la consulta es el siguiente

```
SELECT ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre, (SELECT SUM(ventas.Cantidad) from ventas WHERE comprador.id_com = ventas.id_com) as total_ventas
from comprador, ventas 
where comprador.id_com = ventas.id_com
group by 
comprador.nombre
```

es ahi donde me aparece el error antes mencionado, cualquier tipo ayuda es bienvenida

Answer (score 0):

En las consultas SQL con funciones agregadas, como en tu caso el group by, tanto el `SELECT` como el `GROUP BY` deberán de tener los mismos campos:

```
SELECT ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre, (SELECT SUM(ventas.Cantidad) 
             from ventas 
             WHERE comprador.id_com = ventas.id_com) as total_ventas
from comprador, ventas where comprador.id_com = ventas.id_com 
group by ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre
```

Mas información referente a la consultas con `GROUP BY` aquí [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: que tal amigo, aprecio mucho tu ayuda sin embargo lo intente pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: No te funciona porque la subselect debería entrar en el group by. Lamentablemente esto no es posible sin hacer la subselect en el FROM

Comment: que tal buenos dias, pude lograr mi cometido al final la consulta quedo de esta forma

Comment: SELECT ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre, sum(cantidad) as total_ventas
from comprador, ventas
where ventas.id_com= comprador.id_com
group by ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre
order by ventas.id_com

Comment: @HugoCostilla Te recomiendo contestar a tu propia pregunta como respuesta, y marcarla como la respuesta correcta. De todas formas, el link que te he pasado de w3schools, es una página bastante fiable donde podrás aprender muchas cosas de sql y diversos lenguajes

Answer (score 0):

Intenta este acercamiento con la subselect en el FROM y luego llamándola en la select principal. En la subselect te traes el sumatorio y el id del comprador al que afecta la suma. Luego muestra el sumatorio en la select principal y une el comprador de la subselect con el comprador de la select principal:

```
SELECT ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre, totales.cantidad_total
from comprador, ventas,
 (  
    SELECT comprador.id_com as c2, SUM(ventas.Cantidad) as cantidad_total from ventas, comprador WHERE comprador.id_com = ventas.id_com GROUP BY comprador.id_com
 )  totales 

where comprador.id_com = ventas.id_com AND totales.c2 = comprador.id_com
```

Debería hacer el truco, si no te funciona comenta y lo vemos =)

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te han mencionado arriba, el group by tiene que tener los mismos campos de la select, exceptuando el campo de la función de grupo.

El problema que tienes es que, no te deja el group by porque estás poniendo en un campos de la select una subconsulta, el group by solo te funcionaría dentro de esa subconsulta.

Si quieres que te funcione tal como lo tienes hecho deberías poner algo así:

> **SELECT ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre, SUM(ventas.Cantidad) as total_ventas from comprador, ventas  where comprador.id_com =
>   ventas.id_com group by  ventas.id_com, comprador.nombre**

Espero que sea de tu ayuda y te funcione.

Comment: Con eso obtienes el sumatorio de todas la ventas.  El OP quiere que la suma de ventas venga definida por cada comprador.

Answer (score 0):

Existen 3 errores conceptuales en esa consulta, primero que nada, el group by debe contener todos los campos de la consulta que no sean "calculados" (Dígase, funciones agregadas y sub-consultas). Segundo, ya estas haciendo un join con la tabla `ventas` cuando escribes `from comprador, ventas`, por lo cual la consulta es innecesaria, para expresarla mas claramente (al menos en SQL-Server) deberías escribirlo:

```
FROM 
comprador c
INNER JOIN --O LEFT JOIN si quieres que aparezca los compradores sin ventas.
ventas v
ON v.id_com = c.id_com
```

Por ultimo, y dado que la sub-consulta es innecesaria dado lo anteriormente visto, los campos que necesitaríamos proyectar son: `c.nombre`, `c.id_com` (puede ser `v.id_com` pero aunque sean iguales prefiero que pertenezcan a la misma tabla que `c.nombre`) y `SUM(v.cantidad) TotalCantidadVentas` (el resultado de la función agregada `SUM` como `TotalCantidadVentas`). Aqui, por tener una funcion agregada, es estrictamente necesario que el resto de los campos fuera de la función agregada estén en la definición del `Group By`, es decir:

```
GROUP BY c.id_com, c.nombre
```

Nuestra consulta quedaría finalmente como:

```
SELECT c.id_com, c.nombre, SUM(v.cantidad) TotalCantidadVentas
FROM 
comprador c
INNER JOIN --O LEFT JOIN si quieres que aparezca los compradores sin ventas.
ventas v
ON v.id_com = c.id_com
--WHERE 
GROUP BY c.id_com, c.nombre
--Having
```

En el `WHERE` puedes utilizar expreciones con la consigna de que todos los campos del deben existir en el Group By.

En el `HAVING` puedes utilizar expreciones con cualquier campo "proyectable" de la consulta. Desde el Sum que tenemos u otras como AVG, MAS, MIN, COUNT y hasta sub-consultas que solo utilice los campos proyectables de la consulta superior en sus condiciones internas.